# Segue from NavigationBarItem to UINavigationViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I have a tutorial and at the end of the tutorial I want to push from a UIViewController to a UINavigationViewController. I need the UINavigationViewController because I'm using [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController) . The view which is managed by this UINavigationViewController is a UITableViewController. Okay so far everything is easy to understand right? No problem. But now it gets weird.
Now I use this code (IBAction):

```
HomeNavViewController *home = [[HomeNavViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewControllerhome animated:YES];
```

Everything I get is an app termination from the debugger.
Does anyone have experienced this already?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Here is the error message (sorry I forgot to post it in the first place :) ):

```
2013-05-14 16:43:07.313 187ers[1124:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2c3e012 0x210be7e 0x2bf1b6a 0x2bf1a20 0x2aca3f 0xeac4 0x340103 0x34042b 0x34df80 0x54a223 0x346ee3 0x347167 0x3471a7 0xe4cc 0x211f705 0x2602c0 0x49ca64 0x211f705 0x2602c0 0x260258 0x321021 0x32157f 0x3206e8 0x28fcef 0x28ff02 0x26dd4a 0x25f698 0x2b99df9 0x2b99ad0 0x2bb3bf5 0x2bb3962 0x2be4bb6 0x2be3f44 0x2be3e1b 0x2b987e3 0x2b98668 0x25cffc 0x2e4d 0x2d75)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Done. Sorry I forgot to post it

Answer (score 0):

Your error is caused by an illegal operation on an NSMutableArray (you try to insert a nil object in NSMutableArray). Check your code `HomeNavViewController` `viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear (if you implement them) and make sure that you don't try to insert nil objects into an array

Also if you execute code after `[self presentModalViewControllerhome animated:YES];` check for the same problem insert nil object into NSMutableArray.

Comment: You should exceptions breackpoint to see which line is causing the crash.